# How to stop visit same website tab in single time?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I stop visiting users same website page from multiple tabs? can I do it with javascript?

Comment: If you'd do it then you should do it with JavaScript. Do some research on how to communicate between open tabs. There are API's like the [`Broadcast Channel API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) which allow you to talk to other tabs. From there you might be able to develop a system which checks knows if there already is an open tab and close the other if needed.

Comment: To be clear, you don't want visitors to your site to have it open in multiple tabs? Is that what you are saying? The short answer is that you can't, it is both a fundamental part about how HTTP works, as well as how browsers have implemented tabs and/or windows. That said, as Emiel pointed out, you can write code that in one way or another disables your application if it detects this has happened. So you can't stop it, but you can stop your application from supporting it maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("_instance=true") === -1) {
    document.cookie = "_instance=true";
    // Set the onunload function
    window.onunload = function(){
        document.cookie ="_instance=true;expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT";
    };
    // Load the application
    }
    else {
         alert(" Security Alerts.You Are Opening Multiple Window. This window will now close.");
         var win = window.open("about:blank", "_self"); win.close();
    // Notify the user
    }
    };
</script>
```